# App crashes when I click on a button in action bar

Tags: android, android-intent

My app had action overflow, where I had put the settings button, which I replaced settings button. When ever I click on the settings button, the app crashes

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  

  switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case android.R.id.home:
       finish();
       break;
       // Something else
     case R.id.action_settings:
     Intent  intent = new Intent(this, Setting.class);
       startActivity(intent);
     default:
       break;
     }  
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of your logcat when it crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whitout knowing the output of your logcat, first thing that comes to my mind. Have you added Setting.java to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

```
<activity
        android:name=".Setting">
</activity>
```

Comment: Should be a comment...

Comment: missed on that, will add and see

Comment: I'm providing an answer to the question, thought without knowing the logcat, it's just a guess, but most of the times, the problem is that when launching the Activity, it is not added in AndroidManifest.xml